# Linearization of product of three variables

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, binary-programming

Let $h=xyz$, where $x,y \in \{0,1\}$ and $z \in [0,T]$ with $T>0$ being a constant. Is there any method that can linearize  $h=xyz$? For example, if $h=xy$ the method in [here](https://www.leandro-coelho.com/linearization-product-variables/) can be used to linearize this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to model $h=xyz$, where $x,y \in \{0,1\}$ and $z \in [0,T]$ with $T>0$ being a constant. We first linearize $xy$ in the same way as described in the link you posted. To do so, we introduce a new variable $w$ along with the following constraints:

$$w \leq x$$
$$w \leq y$$
$$w \geq x+y-1$$
$$ 0 \leq w \leq 1$$
All that is left now is to model $h=wz$. Since $z$ is upper bounded by $T$ and lower bounded by 0 we can do this in the following way:

$$h\leq T w$$
$$h \leq z$$
$$h \geq z - (1-w)T$$
$$h \geq 0$$.

So, if either $x$ or $y$ is zero, it will follow from the first two and the fourth constraint that $w = 0$. From constraint 5 and 8 it will then follow that $h=0$.

If, however $x=y=1$, constraints 1 to 3 will force $w=1$. Constraints 6 and 7 will then force $h=z$.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly better answer to this (better in the sense is that it gives the convex hull) is to use the 8 inequalities:

$$ h \leq z$$
$$h \leq T x$$
$$h \leq Ty$$
$$x \leq 1$$
$$y \leq 1$$
$$z \leq T$$
$$h \geq Tx + Ty + z - 2T$$
$$h \geq 0$$